# How to test angular event emitter in a parent component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I want to write a unit test to test the event emitter in a parent component.

html code in parent component:

```html
  <ng-container *ngIf="canPageBeDisplayed()">
    <wizard-sidebar-item-group *ngFor="let group of sidebarGroups" [sidebarItems]="group"
      [isCurrentPage]="isCurrentPage" (removeItem)="removeItem($event)"></wizard-sidebar-item-group>
  </ng-container>
```

component ts code in parent component:

```js
  public removeItem(item: SummaryItem): void {
    if (item.actionState !== 'required') {
      this.wizardService.updateSummaryItem(item);
    }
  }
```

How could I test `(removeItem)="removeItem($event)"`?

Comment: You would do what is necessary for the child component to emit such an event, either by getting a reference to the child (using debugElement) and cheating by emitting an event directly, or by using the UI as a real user would do to trigger the emission of the event by the child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a class to your wizard-sidebar-item-group like:

```html
<wizard-sidebar-item-group class="wizard" ... >
```

Then the test could be something like:

```js
it('remove item should be triggered', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    spyOn(component, 'removeItem');
    
    const wizardElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.wizard'));
    wizardElement.triggerEventHandler('removeItem', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```